# Suggestion : Making parallel call from my service to another micro service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice, executor

I have a requirement as follows

- Make a DB call based on certain criteria and fetch list of result
- For each record present in list, make a GET api call to a microservice
- Consolidate all result from micro-service and give response

I want to make the second step parallel. Now I know based on data that no more than 15 records will be present in list. So I thought of using executorservice for this.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())
```

Now I am not very confident as to whether

1. Is using `ExecutorService` the best approach for my scenario. Or I should be using something else
2. Should I create a new executor like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors())` or let container inject a managed Executor using `@Autowired`

Comment: When you say 'create a new executor like ...', do you mean _inline_, or in some class constructor, etc.?  `ExecutorService` is certainly a reasonable way to parallelise something like this.  A (probably) better option (if possible) would be to modify the micro service to be able to handle a batched query like this (multipart, or similar) and have _that_ handle the threading requirements (then instead of both services having up to 15 threads for handling this, only one of them needs it).

Comment: @user2478398 I am creating inline. In the method in which I will be making a service call to another microservice

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `List` of records, you may iterate through it using `parallelStream`.

```
List<SomeObject> objectList = resultFromDB();
objectList.parallelStream()
          .map(obj -> makeApiCallInParallel(obj))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`parallelStream` will perform API calls in parallel. The number of parallel calls is limited by the number of threads of your CPU.

You may increase it using JVM property:

`-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=20`